# Joining Oracle ApEx collections to actual tables

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle10g, oracle-apex

Within Oracle ApEx is it possible to join an actual table in your schema to an Oracle ApEx Collection, as I am having trouble doing so?

Basically have the following scenario:

```
select c001,  -- employee id from collection
       c002,
       c003   -- employee dept no from collection
from   apex_collections,
       emp
where  emp.id = c001
and    emp.deptno = c003;
```

Is the above possible or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes it's possible, what problem are you having exactly?

Comment: Hi @Tony, managed to solve the issue just don't know how to change the status of this thread to solved.

Comment: Is the answer likely to be helpful to others?  If so, add your own answer - not sure if you can accept it though.  Otherwise, if you can't delete the question we can close it.

Comment: This should be deleted if abandoned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can join apex collection with our schema tables..it will work..

```
select c001,  -- employee id from collection
       c002,
       c003   -- employee dept no from collection
from   apex_collections,
       emp emp
where  emp.empno = c001
and    emp.deptno = c003;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
I have this table person (personid, ...., telephone_numbers)
in which the column "telephone numbers" is a nested table.
In the example below I'm trying to use this into collections and display the count of telephone numbers that the row has.
-- */
DECLARE
  telno telephone_number_table; -- variable name and type.
  cnt INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT p.telephone_numbers -- accept the nested table into the variable
    INTO telno
    FROM person p
   WHERE p.personid = 1;

  SELECT COUNT(*) -- I'm using COUNT(*) here, you can use your valid column listing.
    INTO cnt
    FROM person p
    CROSS JOIN TABLE(telno) tel -- use a cross join with alias
   WHERE p.personid = 1;

  dbms_output.put_line(cnt);
END;
/
```